# Clone an element after the drag and drop angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Good evening,
I block on a problem on angular js or js quite simply. There must be elements when I drag the element.
When I drag an element it must be cloned automatically in the same place :

If for example I drag the element in yellow below it should be cloned in the same place
[image]

For now here are my codes (I use angular JS and the CdkDragDrop library for darg and drop)

My code in html

```
    <div id="toolbar">

      <div id="plot" style="margin: 20px 10px;float: left;"  cdkDrag>
        <svg
          width="25.792181"
          height="25.02323"
          viewBox="0 0 10.599931 11.402646"
          version="1.1"
          id="svg124">
          <defs
            id="defs118">
            <linearGradient
              xlink:href="#linearGradient3732"
              id="linearGradient3738"
              x1="-838.93042"
              y1="919.42883"
              x2="-573.70636"
              y2="1191.3606"
              gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
              gradientTransform="translate(337.64626,-346.59053)" />
            <linearGradient
              id="linearGradient3732">
              <stop
                style="stop-color:#ce5c00;stop-opacity:1"
                offset="0"
                id="stop3734" />
              <stop
                id="stop3740"
                offset="0.49951562"
                style="stop-color:#f57900;stop-opacity:1" />
              <stop
                style="stop-color:#fcaf3e;stop-opacity:1"
                offset="1"
                id="stop3736" />
            </linearGradient>
            <filter
              style="color-interpolation-filters:sRGB"
              id="filter3779">
              <feGaussianBlur
                stdDeviation="3.1485944"
                id="feGaussianBlur3781" />
            </filter>
            <linearGradient
              xlink:href="#linearGradient3607"
              id="linearGradient3629"
              gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
              x1="300.55362"
              y1="387.68179"
              x2="645.22467"
              y2="387.68179" />
            <linearGradient
              id="linearGradient3607">
              <stop
                style="stop-color:#2e3436;stop-opacity:1;"
                offset="0"
                id="stop3609" />
              <stop
                style="stop-color:#2e3436;stop-opacity:0;"
                offset="1"
                id="stop3611" />
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient
              xlink:href="#linearGradient3620"
              id="linearGradient3626"
              x1="432.33682"
              y1="328.91965"
              x2="341.33682"
              y2="349.91965"
              gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
              gradientTransform="translate(0,-8)" />
            <linearGradient
              id="linearGradient3620">
              <stop
                style="stop-color:#eeeeec;stop-opacity:1;"
                offset="0"
                id="stop3622" />
              <stop
                style="stop-color:#eeeeec;stop-opacity:0;"
                offset="1"
                id="stop3624" />
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient
              xlink:href="#linearGradient3695"
              id="linearGradient3701"
              x1="335.16861"
              y1="284.09067"
              x2="355.67471"
              y2="284.09067"
              gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
              gradientTransform="translate(-1.4142136,-12.242641)" />
            <linearGradient
              id="linearGradient3695">
              <stop
                style="stop-color:#ffffff;stop-opacity:1;"
                offset="0"
                id="stop3697" />
              <stop
                style="stop-color:#ffffff;stop-opacity:0;"
                offset="1"
                id="stop3699" />
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient
              xlink:href="#linearGradient3695"
              id="linearGradient3705"
              gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
              gradientTransform="translate(26.870058,122.10765)"
              x1="335.16861"
              y1="284.09067"
              x2="355.67471"
              y2="284.09067" />
            <linearGradient
              xlink:href="#linearGradient3785"
              id="linearGradient3791"
              x1="533.8656"
              y1="497.99045"
              x2="422.7713"
              y2="541.8407"
              gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" />
            <linearGradient
              id="linearGradient3785">
              <stop
                style="stop-color:#f6f6f5;stop-opacity:1;"
                offset="0"
                id="stop3787" />
              <stop
                style="stop-color:#f6f6f5;stop-opacity:0;"
                offset="1"
                id="stop3789" />
            </linearGradient>
          </defs>
          <g
            id="layer1"
            transform="translate(-113.02132,-128.77418)">
            <g
              id="g66"
              transform="matrix(0.0225105,0,0,0.02174846,111.49815,126.82565)">
              <rect
                style="fill:#212453;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#2e3436;stroke-width:8.94427204;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
                id="rect3713"
                class="colorable-fill"
                width="305.10339"
                height="305.10339"
                x="-531.41095"
                y="549.41931"
                ry="33.370686"
                transform="matrix(0.89442719,-0.4472136,0.89442719,0.4472136,0,0)" />
              <path
                id="path3760"
                d="M 304.52691,536.38952 135.51472,535.17632 56.627417,479.56109 173.69848,407.07581 Z"
                style="opacity:0.25714285;fill:#2e3436;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;filter:url(#filter3779)"/>
              <g
                id="g3762">
                <path
                  style="fill:#212453;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#2e3436;stroke-width:8;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none"
                  d="m 300.125,93.59375 c -16.56854,0 -30,8.29133 -30,18.53125 0,0.44371 0.0129,0.87659 0.0625,1.3125 l -109,338.96875 0.15625,0.25 C 165.14008,497.97989 225.81392,534 300.09375,534 c 74.27984,0 134.95367,-36.02011 138.75,-81.34375 l 0.1875,-0.25 -109,-338.96875 c 0.0496,-0.43591 0.0937,-0.86879 0.0937,-1.3125 0,-10.23992 -13.43146,-18.53125 -30,-18.53125 z"
                  id="path2816"
                  class="colorable-fill"/>
                <ellipse
                  style="fill:url(#linearGradient3629);fill-opacity:1;stroke:none"
                  id="path2833"
                  transform="matrix(0.12799764,0,0,0.12799764,261.23491,62.99806)"
                  cx="300.55362"
                  cy="387.68179"
                  rx="138.9292"
                  ry="85.862968" />
                <path
                  style="fill:#eeeeec;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none"
                  d="m 401.41403,355.49514 c -25.34145,16.67832 -61.34581,27.09861 -101.28903,27.09861 -40.63648,0 -77.21254,-10.78123 -102.625,-27.96875 l -16.84375,51.9375 c 24.22263,25.16994 68.64964,42.03125 119.46875,42.03125 49.63975,0 93.17537,-16.09367 117.73492,-40.29858"
                  id="path3681"/>
                <path
                  style="fill:#eeeeec;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none"
                  d="m 363.93651,235.0084 c -19.10714,6.1199 -40.80431,13.58535 -63.81151,13.58535 -23.03341,0 -44.74724,-7.46266 -63.875,-13.59375 l -18.9375,58.6875 c 23.12729,10.62656 51.78306,20.90625 82.8125,20.90625 30.72112,0 59.10585,-10.16273 82.10378,-20.59877"
                  id="path3666" />
                <path
                  style="fill:url(#linearGradient3626);fill-opacity:1;stroke:none"
                  d="m 327.28942,129.16398 -15.15228,5.05076 61.02757,378.46058 c 32.14286,-10 62.85353,-58.11967 58.81292,-58.11967 -4.04061,0 -103.67805,-323.37137 -104.68821,-325.39167 z"
                  id="path3615" />
                <path
                  style="fill:url(#linearGradient3701);fill-opacity:1;stroke:none"
                  d="m 333.7544,249.57416 8.48529,46.66905 12.02081,-4.24264 v -45.25484 z"
                  id="path3685"/>
                <path
                  id="path3703"
                  d="m 362.03867,383.92445 8.48529,46.66905 12.02081,-4.24264 12.72792,-52.3259 z"
                  style="fill:url(#linearGradient3705);fill-opacity:1;stroke:none" />
              </g>
              <path
                id="path3783"
                d="m 536.33009,477.5199 -224.496,106.73759 c 0,0 -1.41421,19.09189 4.24264,18.38478 5.65686,-0.70711 217.58178,-107.68734 217.58178,-107.68734 10,-8 8.32843,-16.72792 2.67158,-17.43503 z"
                style="opacity:0.26122448;fill:url(#linearGradient3791);fill-opacity:1;stroke:none"/>
            </g>
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>

      <div style="margin: 20px 10px;float: left;"  cdkDrag>
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          id="svg4558"
          version="1.1"
          viewBox="0 0 6.1315413 6.1315413"
          height="6.1315413mm"
          width="6.1315413mm">
          <defs
            id="defs4552" />
          <g
            transform="matrix(0.74755917,0,0,0.74755917,-6.5412547,-83.330711)"
            id="layer1">
            <g
              id="g4532"
              transform="translate(-51.574849,-17.519194)">
              <g
                transform="matrix(0.24031004,0,0,0.24031004,52.059335,104.22313)"
                id="g4537">
                <circle
                  style="fill:#a9a9a9;fill-opacity:0.67346939;stroke-width:0.26458332"
                  r="17.065624"
                  cy="120.12604"
                  cx="51.461456"
                  id="path10" />
                <g
                  id="g4527"
                  transform="matrix(0.85714286,0,0,0.85714286,7.3516365,17.160862)">
                  <circle
                    id="path12"
                    class="colorable-fill"
                    cx="51.461456"
                    cy="120.12604"
                    r="12.964583"
                    style="fill:#212453;stroke-width:0.26458332" />
                </g>
              </g>
            </g>
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>

      <div style="margin: 20px 10px;float: left;"  cdkDrag>
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          version="1.0"
          width="14.26548pt"
          height="14.099306pt"
          viewBox="0 0 14.26548 14.099307"
          preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
          id="svg6">
          <defs
            id="defs10" />
          <g
            transform="matrix(0.00111467,0,0,-0.00110184,-0.00127172,14.101053)"
            id="g4"
            style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-opacity:1">
            <path
              d="m 2775,12790 c -202,-30 -409,-130 -645,-313 -139,-109 -444,-413 -727,-727 -148,-164 -324,-344 -494,-506 -145,-138 -316,-305 -379,-370 -553,-572 -667,-1038 -365,-1500 184,-283 388,-501 925,-992 230,-209 599,-569 1175,-1144 L 3105,6400 1744,5038 C 996,4288 361,3648 333,3615 -67,3138 -103,2736 212,2267 c 126,-188 308,-376 728,-754 273,-246 361,-334 703,-705 336,-364 575,-576 779,-691 315,-176 642,-151 996,77 178,114 284,216 1629,1560 L 6400,3105 7747,1759 C 8489,1019 9134,379 9182,338 9360,184 9547,76 9715,29 9778,11 9822,6 9925,6 c 170,-1 264,22 440,109 243,120 448,300 849,745 305,340 339,374 701,710 419,388 578,559 716,769 82,124 125,224 150,346 22,104 23,162 8,272 -27,198 -126,400 -312,638 -43,55 -604,624 -1426,1448 l -1356,1357 1361,1363 c 748,749 1383,1389 1411,1422 151,180 250,350 299,511 24,77 27,107 28,224 0,152 -21,258 -78,385 -124,277 -288,467 -836,965 -338,308 -358,327 -692,690 -345,375 -519,536 -720,667 -190,125 -319,167 -508,167 -164,1 -279,-28 -440,-109 -253,-128 -275,-147 -1768,-1639 l -1352,-1351 -909,910 c -632,633 -976,986 -1131,1160 -367,412 -638,669 -855,813 -260,172 -510,245 -730,212 z"
              id="path2"
              class="colorable-fill"
              style="fill:#212453;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-opacity:1" />
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>

      <div style="margin: 20px 10px;float: left;"  cdkDrag>
        <svg
          xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          id="svg838"
          version="1.1"
          viewBox="0 0 8.3430511 5.1630636"
          height="5.1630635mm"
          width="8.343051mm">
          <defs
            id="defs832" />
          <g
            transform="matrix(0.71761546,0,0,0.71761546,-85.511507,-122.44058)"
            id="layer1">
            <g
              style="fill:#212453;stroke:none"
              id="g4"
              transform="matrix(0.00116284,0,0,-7.804261e-4,117.20473,179.50191)">
              <path
                id="path2"
                class="colorable-fill"
                d="M 5429,10747 C 5101,10399 4123,9364 3256,8446 2389,7528 1681,6773 1682,6769 c 3,-5 3696,-3918 4201,-4449 l 152,-160 3,1090 2,1090 h 2729 c 1500,0 2769,3 2819,6 l 92,7 V 6776 9200 H 8860 6040 v 1090 c 0,600 -3,1090 -7,1089 -5,0 -276,-285 -604,-632 z"/>
            </g>
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>

      <div style="margin: 20px 10px;float: left;" cdkDrag>
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          width="7.4594655mm"
          height="7.4594655mm"
          viewBox="0 0 7.4594655 7.4594655"
          version="1.1"
          id="svg4630">
          <defs
            id="defs4624" />
          <g
            id="layer1"
            transform="translate(-87.042148,-139.60315)">
            <circle
              style="opacity:1;fill:none;fill-opacity:0;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#212453;stroke-width:0.75599998;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1;paint-order:stroke markers fill"
              id="path4518"
              cx="90.771881"
              cy="143.33289"
              r="3.3517327" />
            <text
              style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:6.9625988px;line-height:1.25;font-family:'Microsoft JhengHei UI';-inkscape-font-specification:'Microsoft JhengHei UI';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.17406496"
              x="88.907135"
              y="145.45978"
              id="text4522"><tspan
     id="tspan4520"
     x="88.907135"
     y="145.45978"
     style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-family:'lato';stroke-width:0.17406496">A</tspan></text>
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>

      <div style="margin: 20px 10px;float: left;"  cdkDrag>
        <svg
          xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          width="7.4594655mm"
          height="7.4594655mm"
          viewBox="0 0 7.4594655 7.4594655"
          version="1.1"
          id="svg5205">
          <defs
            id="defs5199" />
          <g
            id="layer1"
            transform="translate(-124.59499,-133.38274)">
            <circle
              style="opacity:1;fill:none;fill-opacity:0;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#212453;stroke-width:0.756;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1;paint-order:stroke markers fill"
              id="path4518-1"
              cx="128.32472"
              cy="137.11247"
              r="3.3517327" />
            <g
              id="g4571"
              transform="matrix(0.12183826,0,0,0.12183826,114.129,120.79595)">
              <text
                id="text4522-7"
                y="146.90227"
                x="98.160301"
                style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:47.53210831px;line-height:1.25;font-family:'lato';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:1.18830276"
                ><tspan
       style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-family:'lato';stroke-width:1.18830276"
       y="146.90227"
       x="98.160301"
       id="tspan4520-3"
       >A</tspan></text>
              <text
                id="text4565"
                y="146.82382"
                x="122.73353"
                style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:21.85655975px;line-height:1.25;font-family:'lato';letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.54641402"
                ><tspan
       style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-family:'lato';stroke-width:0.54641402"
       y="146.82382"
       x="122.73353"
       id="tspan4563"
       >1</tspan></text>
            </g>
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>

    </div>
```